# how to show Custom Post Type (CPT) to another my Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

how to show Custom Post Type (CPT) to another my Wordpress website??

```
<?php
// those two lines at the very top
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/path/to/your/wordpress/wp-load.php');

// ... rest of your code like for example ...

query_posts('showposts=1');
while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more...</a></p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

refer to this Post: [Show blog posts on non-wordpress site with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914271/show-blog-posts-on-non-wordpress-site-with-php/76525841)

i can use the above code to show posts to another Wordpress website .. but looking for the solution for Custom Post Types